# remember me checkbox in login using cookie in codeignitor

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-cookies, remember-me

i want to save email and password on clicking remember me checkbox and cookie should get set on remember me.login is working fine. kindly help me with my code in codeignitor here is my controller code:

```
       public function loginaction()
        {

       $email=$this->input->post('email');
            $password=$this->input->post('password');
            $where = array('email'=>$email,'password'=>$password);
            $tbname='login';
            $query = $this->Insert_Model->viewdata($tbname,$where);

                    if(empty($query))
                    {
                        $data['msg']="Invalid email or password";
                        $this->load->view('login',$data);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        redirect('dashboardv1');
                    }



        }
```

below is cookie code which i implemented:

```
function set()

   {

       $cookie= array(

           'name'   => 'chkremember',
           'value'  => 'test',                            
           'expire' => '300',                                                                                   
           'secure' => TRUE

       );

       $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);



   }



   function get()

   {

       echo $this->input->cookie('chkremember',true);

   }
```

Comment: where is cookie code ?

Comment: i edited post. please have a look if its clear now.

Comment: you need to add helper cookie
`$this->load->helper('cookie')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly you have to include cookie helper as I mention in the comment section

After that in your controller

```
public function loginaction()
    {
        $this->load->helper('cookie');
        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        $password=$this->input->post('password');
        $where = array('email'=>$email,'password'=>$password);
        $tbname='login';
        $query = $this->Insert_Model->viewdata($tbname,$where);

                if(empty($query))
                {
                    $data['msg']="Invalid email or password";
                    $this->load->view('login',$data);
                } 
                else 
                {
             //first you have to delete old cookie and create new one
                delete_cookie("email");
                delete_cookie("password");
                if ($this->input->post('remember') == 'true') {

                  $userName = array(
                    'name' => 'email',
                    'value' => YOUREMAIL,
                    'expire' => '86500',
                    'prefix' => '',
                    'secure' => FALSE
                  );
                  $this->input->set_cookie($userName);

                  $password = array(
                    'name' => 'password',
                    'value' => YOURPASSWORD,
                    'expire' => '86500',
                    'prefix' => '',
                    'secure' => FALSE
                  );
                  $this->input->set_cookie($password);
                }
                    redirect('dashboardv1');
             }
    }
```

Get the cookie you can use below code

```
<?php echo get_cookie('email'); ?>
<?php echo get_cookie('password'); ?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. your code works fine. can you help me with logout function in controller? i want  form fields to stay filled with email and password by which user logged in as remember me checkbox is selected.

Comment: Thanks please upvote the answer so other developers can use these code.

You just have to use `<?php echo get_cookie('email'); ?>` as value in your input field .and check if isset `get_cookie('email')` then remeber me checkbox is check othewise not.
And your logout controller you just need to unset the session no need to do anything in cookie.